# Couchbase tailable cursor

Tags: couchbase

Is there a concept of tailable cursor in Couchbase?

I mean a cursor which remains open after fetching all data, and yields the new data when they become available.

My objective is to create a worker which will transmit all data from particular view to other resource ([Disco](http://discoproject.org)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something currently available in Couchbase, so you have to query your view each time

Comment: Are there any plans to add this feature?